# R sample dataframe with colmeans condition

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I have a data "TestA" as shown below

```
    IDNUMBER B1 B2 B3 B4..... B46  
    ID1      1  1  0  0 ..... 0  
    ID2      0  1  0  0 ..... 1   
    ID3      0  1  0  0 ..... 1
```

Data has dichotomously scored (0 and 1) with 200 rows and 48 colums. What I want to get is I want to select 50 rows and 48 columns which  each column means has to be between 0 and 1 (will not include 0 and 1).

Basically my output will be like this for 50 rows

```
    IDNUMBER B1 B2 B3 B4..... B46  
    ID45      1  1  0  0 ..... 0  
    ID23      0  1  0  0 ..... 1      
    ID186     0  1  0  0 ..... 1  
    ...
    Colmeans  0.91 0.32 0.03.... (not equal to 0 or 1)
```

PS: Each variable has at least one "1" and one "0"

This is an iterative process that I can't get over it. How do I select (sample or filter) 50 rows with that condition?

Comment: I think you mean rowMeans of columns in selection.  Am I right?  colMeans == 0 means that all elements are `0` and similarly `1` means that all are 1.  What if there is no sample possible with this scenario?   To understand it think like this, if N = 1, then all colMeans will either be 0 or 1.  and there is sample possible with size N = 1.  Now add one more row in that sample.  The vars having mean 0 and new value 0 will still have 0 as their mean.  So there may be a situation that you may not find a sample with desired N.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, if your dataframe is `x`:

```
rbind(x, c('Colmeans', colMeans(x[,-1])))
```

Comment: Actually, I need a help to sample that 50 rows :) How do I select 50 from 200 with the condition?

Comment: @gradienti you could just do that then  
    `sampled_rows <- sample(nrow(x), 50);  rbind(x[sampled_rows,], c('Colmeans', colMeans(x[sampled_rows ,-1])))`

Answer (score 0):

Use `rowMeans` to get the column means of the dataframe. Using `sample` select 50 random rows that has mean between 0 and 1.

```
val <- rowMeans(TestA[-1], na.rm = TRUE)
res <- TestA[sample(which(val > 0 & val < 1), 50), ]
```